# Allow a "/" in Symfony2 Routing

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently building custom CMS and I am looking to allow slashes ("/") in my URL's. I have found a away of making them work but it does cause problems for other pages.

So I have a page that has a URL http://www.example.com/about-us/meet-the-team and it works perfectly with this on the controller: -

```
/**
 * @Route("{slug}", name="livepages", requirements={"slug"=".+"})
 */
public function livepagesAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
     // Some Code Here
}
```

However, I also have other pages in the Admin section that have URL's such as this http://www.example.com/admin/pages/add. No when I try to visit this page, I get a GET Error. The code is as follows: -

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/pages/add", name="addpages")
 */
public function addpagesAction(Request $request)
{
    // Some Code Here
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the /about-us/meet-the-team slug is stored in the database as is.

I've tried a few methods to overcome this and it has caused a few issues. Can anyone help me with some ideas?

Comment: Place the slug route inside routing.yml in the end of file so the routing system first will check for existing routes in the config then it will call `livepagesAction`

Comment: Hi Vadim, how do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Hi Vadim, I understood what you meant in the end. It works a treat. Please post this as an answer and I will give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `slug` route in the end of `routing.yml` configuration file so the routing system will check the other routes first and if none matches it will call `slug` route